# How to use getLastRow when using an array formula, in google sheets. Can I have it ignore a column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the below formula in a google sheet. It works perfectly, except that I have found that getLastRow does not function, since I am using array formulas in column M-P.

How can I get around this? Is it possible to just have getLastRow ignore those columns?

[Link to test sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6t9tmo_Rvhodyc5FglUd_4THzzqBE6ykeCv0wC4Cco/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Open" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn()-2;
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
    s.insertRowAfter(29);
    var cell = s.getRange("H30");
    cell.setFormula("=IF(LEN(C30),MINUS(G30,TODAY()),)");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the value that returns getLastRow lower of higher than the value that you expect? How many rows returns the array formulas? Is there any column that could have the the number of rows that you requires as resulte?

Comment: Hey Ruben, thanks for the reply. So Columns A through L contain data, although only the first few rows. These are the rows that I am concerned with, and want getlastrow to look at.  Columns M through P contain array formula, so as far as getlastrow is concerned, it thinks every row that exists is full. So when I run this script, it puts data in row 1001 (assuming there were 1000 rows before I ran it).

How can I get around this, other then deleting every un-empty row? I found this workaround that I think would apply, but am not skilled enough to be able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Link to test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6t9tmo_Rvhodyc5FglUd_4THzzqBE6ykeCv0wC4Cco/edit?usp=sharing), the formula in Closed!M1 is

```
={"Audit - Resp. Days Left";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F),MINUS(F2:F,I2:I),))}
```

The above formula returns an array with the same height of the Closed sheet which makes that the getLastRow returns the same as maxRows.

In order keep the the formulas and the script unchanged, one alternative is to delete the blank rows in the Closed sheet.

Another alternative is to change the Closed sheet formulas in M1 to P1 to return only the required rows. One way to do this is by using the FILTER function instead of ARRAYFORMULA and IF functions
, i.e., for M1

```
={"Audit - Resp. Days Left";FILTER(MINUS(E2:E,H2:H),LEN(E2:E))}
```

To make this works, be sure to clear the content of the blanks rows.

Comment: Oh, your second idea is interesting and might just work. Ive never used filters before, it looks like its basically doing the same things as the array in this situation?

Comment: This works perfectly! Way simpler then messing with JS. I don't actually understand why or how the FILTER works though, as Ive never used it. Im looking at the  Docs Editor Help on filter, and it doesn't seem to explain whats happening here. Could you dumb it down for me how it works exactly, in this situation?

Comment: Never mind, It kinda works, but something seems off. Would you mind double checking to see if i implemented it correctly?

Comment: Consider to create a [mcve] and if the problem persist, please be more specific about what seems off.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a helper function that checks the last row in the column that is passed in as an argument.

```
function getLastRowInColumn(sheetObj, range) {
return sheetObj.getRange(range)
        .getValues().filter (String).length
}﻿
```

You can call this function from withing your script (see line 'var lr')

```
function onEdit(event) {
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
if(s.getName() == "Open" && event.range.columnStart == 9 && event.value == "Yes") {
var targetSheet = event.source.getSheetByName("Closed");
var lr =  getLastRowInColumn(targetSheet, 'C:C')
var target = targetSheet.getRange(lr+1, 1);
s.getRange(event.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()-2).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(event.range.rowStart);
s.insertRowAfter(29);
var cell = s.getRange("H30");
cell.setFormula("=IF(LEN(C30),MINUS(G30,TODAY()),)");
   }
}
```